# Taking Screenshot when Screen Off on Android 10(Q) Emulator from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, screenshot, screen-capture

I just turned off the screen in the Android 10 Emulator and connect ADB devices in Android studio terminal. Then I have taken screenshot using **screencap** command. After that pulled out the screenshot. But screenshot is coming like full of small square boxes with white and grey colour. When I am using Android 9 or Android 11, the black screenshot is coming. Why I am facing the issue only on Android 10 Emulator? If anybody knows please solve my issue. Thanks in advance

**Android 10 Emulator screenshot when screen off using screencap command**

[image]

**Android 9 Emulator screenshot when screen off using screencap command**
[image]