# How to take a screenshot when the screen is off?

Tags: android

I have an long run APP, it needs to take screenshot every 1 minute and save to disk, everything works fine when the screen is ON, but when the screen is OFF, the screenshot file is not created. I can confirm the APP is still running and the takeScreenshot is executed every 1 minute as the log file is updated continuously.

Is it possible to take APP screenshot when the screen is OFF in the first place?

Comment: It seems that when the screen is off you just get either black or transparent screen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72473777/taking-screenshot-when-screen-off-on-android-10q-emulator-from-android-studio

Comment: taking a screenshot of a turned-off screen doesn't make sense, what I recommend is generating an image with the needed info and saving it, I use this method a lot in my apps where I would create a view, in the background wouldn't show on the screen, with all the data that I need and then save it as bitmap/image

Answer (score 0):

That would not make sense. You are trying to make a screenshot of a black screen. Why would you need to make a screenshot every minute in the first place?